# Set icon based on property value?

Tags: wpf, xaml, mahapps.metro

I need to set a specific icon based on property Value, so for example I've a property called `ConnectionStatus` that is a boolean, now inside the DataTrigger I did the following:

```
<simpleChildWindow:ChildWindow.Style>
    <Style TargetType="simpleChildWindow:ChildWindow">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ConnectionStatus}" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Icon" Value="???" />
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</simpleChildWindow:ChildWindow.Style>
```

I don't know how to pass this content:

```
<simpleChildWindow:ChildWindow.Icon>
    <materialDesign:PackIcon Kind="ServerOff" 
                             Width="22" 
                             Height="22"
                             HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                             VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
</simpleChildWindow:ChildWindow.Icon>
```

inside the value of the setter, someone could help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about declaring the PackIcon as a *static resource*. Then reference it using the resource key?

```
<simpleChildWindow:ChildWindow.Resources>
    <materialDesign:PackIcon x:Key=“icon1” Kind="ServerOff" 
                         Width="22" 
                         Height="22"
                         HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                         VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
</simpleChildWindow:ChildWindow.Resources>

And

<Setter Property="Icon" Value="{Binding Source={StaticResource icon1}}" />
```